# Adding string to object emailaddresses

Tags: string, powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to add a string to the emailaddresses objects of an Exchange mailbox.
But when I add the string, it doesn't show anything.

```
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress, @{Name="EmailAddresses";Expression={($_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike "*smtp*"} | ForEach-Object {$_ -join '_OLD'})}} | where-object {($_.primarysmtpaddress -like "juan@contoso.com")}
```

but when I do a replace operation, it shows me the emailaddresses replaced correctly. Why doesn't it add the string but replace it?

```
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress, @{Name="EmailAddresses";Expression={($_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike "*smtp*"} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "smtp:","Remp:"}) -join "OLD"}} | where-object {($_.primarysmtpaddress -like "juan@contoso.com")}
```

I have also tried with the concatenation operator, but I get the same result.

thanks in advance.

Comment: To add a string to the EmailAddresses array, you can use the += operator to append the string to the array,

Comment: `... |ForEach-Object { $_ -join '_OLD' }` doesn't do anything because you need 2 or more strings in order to "join" anything together. If you want to add `_OLD` at the end of each string, change it to `... |ForEach-Object { "${_}_OLD" }` instead